# Symantec Backup Exec Error 0xe0009413

Tags: backup, symantec

I received the following error on a weekly full backup job on Symantec Backup Exec:

Final error: 0xe0009413 - An error occurred during the snapshot cleanup, or could not locate a snapped volume from which to back up.

I am backing up a Windows 2003 Server.  Other backup jobs have run successfully.

Any tips?

Comment: Ugh, Backup Exec should have a place in the cryptic error message hall of fame. I don't know how much time I lost over the course of a year troubleshooting stuff like this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What steps have you troubleshot already?  Have you looked through the Symantec online KB?  Have you examined entries like:

http://seer.support.veritas.com/docs/273983.htm

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I found more guidance on http://seer.entsupport.symantec.com/docs/264616.htm  

I just went though these steps.  Hopefully, that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1.) Make sure that ANY local volume shadow copies you're taking, are turned off. We've had QUITE a bit of conflicting information from Symantec regarding running local VSC, but have found that when we talked to the techs, they've all advised we don't run VSC on the same server.

2.) If you absolutely, positively have to run VSC, (like, there's a group of users who love deleting things and making you restore them via VSC and they're holding your family hostage or something) you could try resetting the entire kit-and-caboodle by using ["vssadmin"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754968(WS.10).aspx) to delete all current *present* volume shadow copies, then delete them.

In addition to the above, have you presented/removed a disk, (such as from a SAN via fiberchannel, etc?) recently? Make sure it's no longer present in your system, and that you haven't inadvertently attempted to take a volume shadow copy snapshot of it.

Along the same side of the coin, you may have "stale" volume shadow copy snapshots present for disks that are no longer there. That could be exacerbating your issue. Suggest same above, to delete those, since I believe that vssadmin is the only way you can see some of them.

Don't quote me on this, but I think that you also have to expand the default size of the VSC *from* 300 *to* 500, however I'm not entirely sure. I do remember that it took me quite a bit of googling though and in the end, this made Symantec happy.

Sorry, ordinarily I'd be more clear and try to give some steps but I can't seem to find where I documented this, the last time it worked and the primary backup guy is out for the day, (only other guy who'd have them in his email.)

Good luck!